Не меняется IP в библиотеке requests в Python
import requests

proxies = {'http': 'http://185.162.229.159:80',
            'https': 'http://185.162.229.159:80',}

url = 'https://httpbin.org/ip'
response = requests.get(url,proxies=proxies)
data = response.json()
ip = data['origin']
print(ip)

Вот ошибка: requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ip (Caused by ProxyError('Unable to connect to proxy', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 400 Bad Request')))

Значение 400 означает, что запрос был сформирован неправильно. Другими словами, поток данных, отправленный клиентом на сервер, не соответствовал правилам.
Смотри информацию о 400 html error
Так же у тебя проблема с прокси, нет коннекта
